# Java, For Loop in Class

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, boolean

I'm a novice programmer and I am creating this program where I would like to create a list of booleans of size ten and then set all the values to false. As I have understood in Java one is not supposed to place code directly in a class without surrounding them by a method. However I want this to be done as soon as an instance of the class is created.

My question is then where this should be done. Should I do this in a constructor, should I initialize the list with all its values or have I simply missed something making it completely fine to put a for loop directly in the class? Thanks.

Some of my code was requested so this is the problem here:

```
boolean[] numKeysPressed = new boolean[10];


for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    numKeysPressed[i] = false;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the default value for a boolean (primitive) is false. Since you want it in a List you will have to use Boolean which will be null. You could consider your code to use null as false.

Comment: In the constructor would be fine :)
Post some relevant code, what you have tried and what-not, and we can help you even more :)

Comment: In the [Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: The constructor is the normal place, but if you have several constructors and wish to avoid redundantly initializing the list in each, initializing the list when you create it is normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However I want this to be done as soon as an instance of the class is created.
>
> My question is then where this should be done. Should I do this in a constructor..

Yes, that is perfect place for it since purpose of constructor is to initialize newly created object with proper state.

In case you have few constructors you can use initialization block which will be added at start of each constructor automatically by compiler

```
class YourClass{

    List<Boolean> list; 

    YourClass(){
        //constructor 1
    }

    YourClass(String s){
        //constructor 2
    }

    {
        //initialization block, will be executed at start of each
        //constructor (right after its super() call).
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            list.add(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

}
```

BTW, if by list you mean `boolean[]` array then it is by default filled with `false` values so you don't need to set it. Simple

```
class YourClass{
    boolean[] list = new boolean[10]; // this array will be filed with false

}
```

Comment: Initialization blocks are certainly the way to do this; they're a lesser-known feature but they do exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put the code inside a constructor.

```
public class MyClass{

    boolean[] numKeysPressed = new boolean[10];

    public MyClass(){
        for(int i = 0; i < numKeysPressed.length; i++){
            numKeysPressed[i] = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Please note that the default value of a boolean is false, so this step is rather unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) (<= click link for tutorial) are for - initializing the members of a class. The Java VM calls one of the constructors of your class when the object is created.

Note that the default value for `boolean` is `false`. Your `for` loop is therefore redundant - all the `boolean` values in the array will already be set to `false` when you create the array.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that all instance variables and arrays in Java are initialized to their 0 equivalent.

This means that `boolean`s and arrays will always be filled in with their 0-equivalent value, which is `false`.

So as long as you have an instance variable (a variable created outside of any methods), it will default to `false`.

Having this line somewhere in your class (and outside of a method) will do the trick:

```
boolean [] array = new boolean[7];
```

And `array` will be a list of 7 elements of type `boolean` whose values are all `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the array as a private member as follows:

```
public class myClass {
     private boolean array1[] = new boolean[] {false, true, false};
}
```

or do it in the constructor as follows:

```
public class myClass {
   private boolean array2[] = null;
   public myClass () {
     Arrays.fill(array2, false);
  }
}
```